# how to find the hour difference between two days in php

Tags: php

I have a two dates

```
$date1="03/17/2012 9:00 PM";
$date2=03/17/2012 9:40 PM";
```

I have to find out the hour difference between these two dates. I know it's 40minutes as manual calculation. But how I calculate this in php.
I have read many docs and tried to calculate. But I got wrong result. See my code

```
$dateDiff=(strtotime($date2)-strtotime($date1))/3600
```

But I got answer 0.7. Its wrong answer

one more

how i show both the hour and minutes ?
eg:

```
$date1="03/17/2012 9:00 PM";
    $date2=04/17/2012 9:40 PM";
```

then i want to show 12 hour and 40 minutes ?

How i will change the code now?

Please help me

Comment: Your using the same variable (date2) twice. Is that a typo?

Comment: Edited my answer to get hours and minutes but you will get more than 12 hours if you go from March (03) to April (04) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$date2 in both strtotime function is wrong

use this

```
$date1="03/17/2012 9:00 PM";
$date2="03/17/2012 9:40 PM";


$diff_seconds  = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);
echo floor($diff_seconds/3600).' hours and '.floor($diff_seconds/60).' minutes';

?>
```

http://codepad.org/5i4QBmlW

Answer (score 0):

Two errors in your code :
 - Your `$date2` is wrong, you forgot a `"` 
 - You try to use `strtotime($date2)` two times and not `$date1` ?

About the results,

If you want a result in minutes, just do `/60`.
If you want a result in hours, just do `/3600`.

```
$result  = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);
echo floor($result/3600).' hours and '.floor(($result%3600)/60).' minutes';
```

It is the best way to do, you have to add %3600 or you will have a problem if you have more than an hour (which will result in 1 hour 80 minutes in this case without %3600).

You can find your result here : [Result in CodePad](http://codepad.org/a7cnWTwm)

If you want to have `12 hour and 40 minutes`, you must have `$date2="03/18/2012 9:40 AM";`